Where can I edit my project's properties in Visual Studio Code?
In Visual Studio for Mac I have the following project properties when I right click my project-->Properties:

Where can I edit my project's properties in Visual Studio Code? Right click is not working in Visual Studio Code. I want to change the Target Android version in Visual Studio Code.


read the VSC doc pages on the language that you use, VSC does not have projects, it is an editor with some terminal features
